# Is that possible to make common dockerfile for multiple containers which has kind of same configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Lets take an example :

```
Dockerfile for container1 : 

FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php5 php5-mysql

Dockerfile for container2 : 

FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php5 php5-mysql php5-dev php5-gd php5-memcache 
php5-pspell
```

So need to avoid,

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php5 php5-mysql
```

as this is same configuration in both Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4):

Check out multistage builds: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Your example would become:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 as image1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php5 php5-mysql

FROM image1 as image2
RUN apt-get install -y php5-dev php5-gd php5-memcache php5-pspell
```

Your build command would need to specify the build target using the `--target` flag.

Comment: FROM image1 as image2 this statement takes all the contents form image1. what if i want only some of them?

Comment: like i dont want php5-mysql from image1 then how its going to be. As u said FROM image1 as image2 but it takes php5-mysql also and i dont want that.

Comment: Using the same strategy, you could have the first image contain only the base dependencies and extend it with two `FROM` directives. You could also `apt-get remove php5-mysql -y` in the second image too.

Comment: if we take above example, build command for container1 dockerfile is : docker build -t multibuild1  .  and  build command for container2 dockerfile is : docker build -t multibuild2 --target image2 . right?  This gives error pull access denied for multibuild, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' and i already login

Comment: I ran the exact commands you posted using my example above and they both worked fine. Did you make any modifications to the example?

Comment: i didnt make any modifications. Its not working for me

Comment: Which version of Docker are you on? `docker -v` Multistage builds require Docker 17.05.

Comment: Docker version 18.03.1-ce is that ok or i need 17.05?

Comment: That should suffice -- I am not sure why it's not working on your system. I am running the same version of Docker as you and using the example above.